# Trying to integrate Azure media player in React JS. but Azure dependent JavaScript lib function doesn't found "amp"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, azure, react-redux, azure-media-services

This is my react js file code to render media player. 
componentDidMount() I imported js file on a load of this page and at the time of render call 'amp' function with options parameter.

```
 componentDidMount () {
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.1.5/azuremediaplayer.min.js";
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    render() { 
            var myOptions = {
                "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
                controls: true,
                autoplay: true,
                width: "640",
                height: "400",
            }
            var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
            myPlayer.src([
                    {
                            "src": "//amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest",
                            "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
                    }
            ]);       
            return (

                <div className="form-horizontal">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="col-sm-4">Azure Media Player</div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                        <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0"></video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default AddItemForm;
```

And console gives this error 
** Line 26:  'amp' is not defined  no-undef**

Answer (score 2):

I think if you load the player's script in a sync way like `script.async = false;`, it would work properly .. I know it would harm the performance, but unfortunately this is the way to go with loading this weirdly packaged player! .. I hate the fact that they didn't make an npm package for it!!

Comment: can the above solution work in react-native?? I am facing issue

Comment: I didn't try much with react-native, but since they are compiling to native code, I think this library shouldn't work, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Gaurravs as per the answer here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fed5e18e-60d4-4053-95f6-6053f735ae9d/azure-media-services-media-player-and-reactnative?forum=MediaServices , the player is not supported in react-native

Answer (score 0):

You could provide **onload** callback for your **script** like this:

```
script.onload = () => this.setState({libraryLoaded: true})
```

And then you can react on the state inside **render** method

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.libraryLoaded) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>
  } else {
    return ... // your component
  }
}
```

Do not forget to initiate the state with `libraryLoaded: false`

You can also check [my package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-mp) which is basically doing this loading under the hood.